# Image texture : how to only sculpt bright areas?

Tags: image, sculpting

I am working on a painting fram based on image texture.
I want ot sculpt the bright areas to highlight them (corner leaves decoration) based on brightness How to sculpt bright areas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: use the image as a Reference or Background image and draw the shape with vertex extrusions. Also you need to decide if your ornement is an object or if it's part of the frame